# Scrolling issue with CollapsingToolbar, Parallax Image and ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, toolbar

I have looked long and hard for a working answer to this problem and it seems either I'm working around a bug in the Design library, or there isn't an answer to what I want to do.

I have a CollapsingToolbar with Parallax Image and a ViewPager below. The ViewPager will only act on horizontal scrolls, while the dark box at the bottom is a TextView which will do vertical scrolls and collapse the Toolbar.

My solution now isn't great for several reasons - Here's a [VIDEO](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fRGIVrwKLx8) to show why.

1. On API22 (and presumably 21), my TitleBar has a shadow under it, which breaks the continuity with the TabLayout below.
2. My ViewPager can only page horizontally. It needs to also accept vertical input and collapse the Toolbar.
3. I have a TextView which pages vertically, collapsing the ToolBar. So it does work, just not as an all-in-one solution with the ViewPager only.

Why the ViewPager can't take care of Horizontal and Vertical scrolling is beyond me. Maybe the functionality doesn't exist in the Design Library yet and there is no workaround. I have tried everything, looked everywhere. This is the best I can do:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"

    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout

    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout

    android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
    app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
    app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

    <ImageView

        android:id="@+id/backdrop"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/md_white_1000"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/backdrop"
        app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
        app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    style="@style/CustomTabs"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager

    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="@dimen/viewpager_padding_default"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView

    android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="@dimen/drawer_padding_default"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <TextView

    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:padding="@dimen/drawer_padding_default"
    android:textColor="@color/textColorPrimary"
    android:background="@drawable/myrect" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton

    android:id="@+id/fab_action"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_action_help"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/drawer_padding_default"
    android:scaleType="center"
    app:borderWidth="0dp"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/main_content"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Can you briefly explain what is not working.

Comment: The dark box at the bottom of the video is @+id/TextView. You can collapse the toolbar with vertical scrolling movements on this view.

The ViewPager however, can only be scrolled horizontally.

I want the ViewPager to also be able to collapse the toolbar and to delete the TextView since I don't need it. It's there now, because it's the only way I can scroll vertically.

Basically I don't understand why the ViewPager will not collapse the Toolbar.

Comment: Just remove `app:layout_collapseMode="pin"` from the `Toolbar`

Comment: That doesn't help fix the problem I am having. I do want the Toolbar to stay pinned also. The problem is that the ViewPager seems to ignore vertical scrolling. I know that vertical scrolling works, since the TextView is able to trigger the collapse. What I don't know, is why the ViewPager will not also trigger the vertical scroll.

There are few examples out there, some suggest having the ViewPager before the AppBar, others include having the TabLayout inside the CollapsingToolbar, but none of them take me any closer to what I'm trying to achieve.

Maybe my XML order is no good? I don't know.

Comment: I think I found the answer to my problem.

I was nesting the ViewPager in a NestedScrollView. I needed to nest the Fragments themselves in the NestedScrollView.

Comment: Would you mind posting a working example? I'm going to give this a shot, but it would be great to see your working solution.

Comment: Just delete the NestedScrollView from the posted XML. Create your own fragment XML with a NestedScrollView as the root element. You'll need to wrap everything else in a Layout since ScrollView only accepts one child element. Inside that you can put nearly anything you want.

Fill your ViewPager with your Fragments and you should be good to go. Feel free to PM if that doesn't mean much to you or you need a hand. Mine seems to work pretty well now..

Answer (score 0):

1)create a separate layout for the viewPager fragments,use NestedScrollView
  as a your root,and add   app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior",to it.

2)add app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" to the viewPager